# How to look up a parent of a parent from a child

Tags: apex, soql, query, nested

I have 2 queries and I cannot figure out how I can nest them.

I have 3 objects that look to each other in this order: `test_result__c` looks up to `test_process__c` which looks up to `contact`.

Here are my queries:

```
List<Test_Result__c> activeParticipantsIds = [
    SELECT Test_Process__r.Candidate__c
    FROM Test_Result__c
    WHERE Status__c = 'New'
];

List<Contact> activeCandidates = [
    SELECT Name
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Id = :activeCandidatesIds[0].Interview_Process__r.Candidate__c
];
```

Do you have any idea how I can merge both queries into one? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look something like this, although I'm not completely sure if it's the right syntax.

```
List<Contact> activeCandidates = [
    SELECT Name
    FROM Contact
    WHERE Id in: (
    SELECT Test_Process__r.Candidate__c
    FROM Test_Result__c
    WHERE Status__c = 'New' Limit 1)
];
```